# How to run 'bash --rcfile' providing FIFO instead of file

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, named-pipes

I can go such thing:

```
$ bash --rcfile <(echo 'PS1="foo> "')
foo>
```

and `<(echo 'PS1="foo> "')` is inplace fifo.

But doing this:

```
$ mkfifo a=rw MYFIFO
$ bash --rcfile MYFIFO
```

now last commands blocks, and on separate terminal:

```
$ echo 'PS1="foo >"' > MYFIFO
```

This make blocked bash command started, however, bash starts with standard `PS1`. How to solve it using named pipes?

Comment: That seems to work as you expect on my machine - you'll need to detail more information e.g. bash version. You should try debugging it using a tool like `strace` on the bash process.

Comment: Ok, probably this is MacOSX issue - works on linux....

Comment: It's definitely an OSX thing - it uses `stat` on the FIFO, which returns a size of `0` when run against the fifo itself, but returns a size of `0xc` when run against the inplace fd insert - seems to be some OSX particular behaviour in this case. SIP is really interfering with any ability to debug this, though.